# Laravel AJAX JSON eturn data related

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, function, relationship

Morning,
Into my ajax code, i would like to return my data article related to unitearticle from my controller like this  :

```
success : function (data){$('.writeuom').text(data->unitearticle->LibUnite);}
```

How can i use this data related ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `data->unitearticle->LibUnite` is not valid JS syntax... To access properties of a JS variable (data) you use dot (`.`) notation: `data.unitearticle.LibUnite`

Comment: Thks @Tim Lewis, it's work !